# How do you access element on unopened page with javascript without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to build a chrome extension that needs to access the value of a specific `<p>` tag off an html element using `document.getElementById` without opening or loading the page. For example, I might want to see what the placeholder for the search bar is on the google homepage using the id of "input."
[Image of google search bar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWe4q.png)

Assume the placeholder value will change. I want to get the placeholder without having to open the chrome new tab everytime I want to access the information.

I think this can be done using the chrome extension background script/service worker (I'm using manifest 3), but I'm unable to figure out how to do this. I am also open to any plain javascript ways to do this.

In addition, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536656/javascript-accessing-elements-from-an-unopened-page) that said to use JQuery (which i want to avoid but will use as a last resort) or using some code that didn't work for me. I also found [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/) about using background script in chrome extensions but it is geared towards putting data into a form instead of taking data out of label and is in manifest 2.

So far the only code I have is getting the request and opening the page. I am unsure what to do next to get the specific element.

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET","http://www.example.org/example.txt");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without opening the page itself"? How should the page be accessed without loading it?

Comment: I edited the question, is it more understandable now?

Comment: "without opening or loading the page" still sounds weird to me. If you don't request any markup, there's no way to access any elements within that markup, so you **need** to load that page in any way

Comment: Are you trying to say it's not possible? In which case I have an alternative, but I have seen chrome extensions that use this property in manifest 2, so I am pretty sure there is a way its possible in manifest 3. For example, I found this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/

Comment: It dependson what you mean by "without loading the page". Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, if you've found an article that already covers such stuff, why not share your attempts to resolve the problem, such that others could check where this is going wrong?

Comment: I learned about how to get HTML from a page using XMLHttpRequest because of the answer that was already provided, but now I am having trouble accessing the existing data from a paragraph tag on the page. The article also provides information on using forms, not taking data. Regardless, thank you for trying to help!

Comment: "I am having trouble accessing the existing data from a paragraph tag on the page" - what does that mean? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you share the code you are using, and the "trouble", it is way easier for others to provide proper help

Answer (score 0):

In the [question that you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536656/javascript-accessing-elements-from-an-unopened-page), the answer provided a set of instructions to complete the task using `JQuery`, but you can just use vanilla javascript. You only need to change step 1, 6 and 7.

1: Get HTML from the page using a get request with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead of `$.get()`

6: Serialize the form data using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instead of `.serialize()`

7: Post serialized data using a post request again with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead of `$.post()` and have a function to get the response.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I have an idea of what to do now! The previous question I linked talks about how to submit data to a form but I need to access already existing information on the page. can you please guide me towards how to do this?

Comment: @Shilab66 hmm im not really sure how to get existing data, sorry.

Comment: Thank you anyways, you helped guide me in the right direction!